# Git commands to run for build machines to keep the repo as trouble free as possible

Tags: git, continuous-integration

We are finding out by trial error which commands we should be running on our git repository (through a Jenkins job) before the BM starts an automatic build.

As an example, we now run a `git remote prune origin` to clean up the branches due to the `cannot lock ref` issue.

Is there a known list of commands that we should be running to keep the repository as clean as possible for the next `git pull --ff-only` to always succeed?

> Note that our repository, due to LFS, is huge and we cannot do what some CIs do, which is reclone the repository with every run.

Comment: `git pull --ff-only` will fail if the local and the upstream branches have diverged. `git reset --hard @{u}` should always work.

Comment: Thanks @sergej - that was my mistake in the question, we do indeed do `git reset --hard`. However, it does not clean the local files which can be left for various reasons. So we run `git clearn -xfd`. We also run the prune command mentioned above. I was just hoping for a list of these commands that might already exist somewhere.